# Questions on case

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I tried to create an example for `cond` and `case` and came up with a simple implementation of the *fizz buzz* problem (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) for details).

My initial version is:

```
(defun is-fizz-buzz (n)
  (cond ((and (zerop (mod n 3)) (zerop (mod n 5))) 'fizz-buzz)
        ((zerop (mod n 3)) 'fizz)
        ((zerop (mod n 5)) 'buzz)
        (t n)))

(defun fizz-buzz (n)
  (princ (case (is-fizz-buzz n)
               ('fizz "Fizz!")
               ('buzz "Buzz!")
               ('fizz-buzz "Fizz-Buzz!")
               (otherwise n))))
```

Now, [@RainerJoswig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69545/rainer-joswig) pointed out to me that my `case` is wrong. I was quite surprised, as it had worked as it should, but as he's **way** more experienced with Lisp than I am, he's most probably right (and in fact, he is).

I tried to read and understand http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm, but now I'm left with more questions than answers. As I didn't want to discuss things in 140 characters and as it may be helpful for other Lisp beginners, I thought to publish my questions here.

Basically, the syntax of `case` is described as

```
case keyform {normal-clause}* [otherwise-clause] => result*
```

`keyform` is easy: It's a form that is evaluated to get the key that is being tested. For sure

```
(is-fizz-buzz n)
```

is a form and it returns a symbol, hence everything looks fine. Additionally, as I learned from *Land of Lisp*, `case` internally works with `eq`, and as `eq` is used to compare symbols, this should be fine as well.

Now, the `normal-clause`: This is defined as

```
(keys form*)
```

`form*` again is simple, it's just a number of forms, basically with an implicit `progn`. For `keys`, it tells me that this is a designator for a list of objects. Phew. Here my questions begin…

[This document](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#designator) tells me that a designator is:

> an object that denotes another object.

Hm. As `case` is working with `eq`, I would have expected that I need to give a symbol here. And why is `keys` a designator for a **list** of objects, not for a single one? May I have multiple symbols that I can compare against in a single branch? I guess the problem here comes down to not really understanding what is meant by a `designator`, but maybe someone can help me and push me into the right direction. How would you explain what a designator is in Lisp?

Then, I started playing around with the code, and I noticed that if I remove the `'` character, things still work. The code

```
(defun fizz-buzz (n)
  (princ (case (is-fizz-buzz n)
               (fizz "Fizz!")
               (buzz "Buzz!")
               (fizz-buzz "Fizz-Buzz!")
               (otherwise n))))
```

produces the very same result as the code above. Why is this? I would not even have expected this to be executable at all, as `(fizz "Fizz!")` to me looks like a function call of `fizz`, which doesn't exist. Why does this work?

And then, the final question is, when I run

```
(case 'quote ('foo 1) ('bar 2))
```

it returns `1` (which does not seem to be logical, I would have expected `nil`). If I change this to

```
(case 'quote ('foo 1) ('bar 2) (otherwise 3))
```

it still returns `1`, not `3` as I now would have expected. From the documentation I don't get why my *otherwise-clause* obviously does not what it should do.

Any hints why these two cases behave like they do?

Comment: whose element is that non-nil atom) or a proper list (denoting itself)."  Thus the symbol `fizz` and the list `(fizz)` both designate the list `(fizz)`, the list `(quote fizz)` designates itself, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CASE` use `EQL` not `EQ`. `EQL` is in most cases the default comparison. Thus case works for identity, numbers and characters.

The keyforms are NOT evaluated. Thus it makes no sense to quote objects. Quoting means stopping evaluation. But there is no evaluation -> no quote.

The keyform is either a single item, or a list of items

```
(case foo
  (bar 'it-is-bar)
  ((1 2) 'one-or-two)
  (1     'one))
  ((apple banana orange) 'either-apple-banana-or-orange)))
```

It also means that one the left side are constants, no variables. `bar` above is the symbol `bar`, not the variable `bar`.

Problem:

```
 (case 'quote
   ('foo 'foo-or-quote))
```

because it really is

```
 (case 'quote
   ((quote foo) 'foo-or-quote))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it now makes a lot more sense :-)). By the way, *Land of Lisp* on page 58 claims that `case` uses `eq` (which doesn't mean that this must be right ;-)).

Comment: @Yes: The ANSI Standard mentions in one place that `EQL` is the default comparison. Unfortunately this is not easily visible from the pages describing `MEMBER`, `POSITION`, `CASE`, ... 'Land of Lisp' is just wrong here. Maybe it is already mentioned in the Errata page for the book?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was able to figure out some of the problems by myself, primarily by reading [this question and the according answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977714/with-case-which-is-the-best-of-these-methods-for-expressing-the-cases). This explains to me why my otherwise-clause didn't work, and it also explains why

```
(case 'quote ('foo 1) ('bar 2))
```

is being evaluated the way it is. So I guess that my `fizz-buzz` function at least should be:

```
(defun fizz-buzz (n)
  (princ (case (is-fizz-buzz n)
               (fizz "Fizz!")
               (buzz "Buzz!")
               (fizz-buzz "Fizz-Buzz!")
               (otherwise n))))
```

#### UPDATE

Okay, now after having re-read the aforementioned question and answers multiple times, I think I finally got what is meant by *a list of objects*, and hence my code should be:

```
(defun fizz-buzz (n)
  (princ (case (is-fizz-buzz n)
               ((fizz) "Fizz!")
               ((buzz) "Buzz!")
               ((fizz-buzz) "Fizz-Buzz!")
               (otherwise n))))
```

Comment: That looks fine, but you don't *have* to put those in lists, because the *keys* part of [`case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm) is "a designator for a list of objects", and a [list designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator) is "an object that denotes a list and that is one of: a non-nil atom (denoting a singleton list whose element is that non-nil atom) or a proper list (denoting itself)."  Thus the symbol `fizz` and the list `(fizz)` both designate the list `(fizz)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out :-). I decided to do it this way to be consistent in style, no matter whether I have lists consisting of a single or of multiple items. Additionally, this helps differentiate `otherwise` from `(otherwise)`. But nevertheless, good to know :-)

Comment: Actually, I just expanded on it in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24067636/1281433), too.  Glad to hear that it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

> For `keys`, it tells me that this is a designator for a list of
>   objects. Phew. Here my questions begin…
>
> [This document](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#designator)
>   tells me that a designator is:
>
> > an object that denotes another object.
>
> Hm. As `case` is working with `eq`, I would have expected that I need
>   to give a symbol here. And why is `keys` a designator for a **list**
>   of objects, not for a single one? May I have multiple symbols that I
>   can compare against in a single branch? I guess the problem here comes
>   down to not really understanding what is meant by a `designator`, but
>   maybe someone can help me and push me into the right direction. How
>   would you explain what a designator is in Lisp?

*I originally posted this as a comment, but I think this might stand as a sufficient answer, if it's the core problem in the question, so I'm adding it as an answer.*

The text you need is in the HyperSpec. [1.4.1.5 Designators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_dae.htm) notes

> The specific nature of the object denoted by a "<> designator"
>   or a "designator for a <>" can be found in the Glossary entry
>   for "<> designator."

The glossary entry for list designator is what you need:

> [list designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator) n. a designator for a list of objects; that is,
>   an object that denotes a list and that is one of: a non-nil atom
>   (denoting a singleton list whose element is that non-nil atom) or a proper list (denoting itself).

Thus the symbol `fizz` (a non-nil atom) and the list `(fizz)` both designate the list `(fizz)`, the list `(quote fizz)` (often abbreviated as `'fizz`) designates itself, etc.

Once you've learned about list designators,they're a very handy concept to use in you own code.  Just document that you accept a list designator, and then convert with `(if (listp x) x (list x))`, and you're in business.  It's very helpful, and you'll find more uses for it than you expect.  E.g., I used it just the other day in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028586/1281433) to [How to group any consecutive numbers or items of a given series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7541144/1281433).